# Why Is My C# Code Only Displaying The First Row from my Database?

Tags: c#, arrays, database, forms, constructor

**My objective**

Hi, I'm trying to code a C# application where I want to retrieve values from a table called Fruits_Table in a Microsoft Access 2016 database called FruitsDatabase.accdb.  I then want to display these values in Labels in my form called label1, label2, label3.

Just for reference, I'm using a constructor called Fruit(string Name, string Color) in another class file called "Fruits.cs".  I then pass this constructor into my PresentationGUI form.

**My Database**

The database has one table named Fruits_Table and in that table it has two columns:  "Name" for the name of the fruit and "Color" for its color.  THREE entries are recorded in the database:  Apple - red, Banana - yellow, Pear - green.

**What I Managed to get working so far**

I managed to make a SUCCESSFUL connection to my database.  So there's no need to worry about that.  Retrieving values from the database is also good to go.

**My Problem**

The problem I have is this:

*Only the FIRST entry in my database seems to be displaying no matter which fruit picture box I click.  In other words, no matter if I click picBox1, picBox2, or picBox3 it ONLY ever displays 'Apple' and 'Red'*

How do I go about iterating through the rows of my database?

```
using System;
...
using system.Windows.Forms;
using system.Data.OleDb;

namespace project1
{
     public partial class PresentationGUI : Form
     {
          private OleDbConnection aConn;
          private OleDbCommand aCmd;
          private OleDbDataReader aReader;

          private string aConnection;
          private string sql;

          Fruit[] aFruit = new Fruit[10];

     public PresentationGUI()
     {
          Initialize Component;

          //This is working fine.
          aConnection = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = FruitsDatabase.accdb;";

          sql = "SELECT * FROM Fruits_Table";
          aCmd = new OleDbCommand();
          aCmd.CommandText = sql;

          aCmd.Connection = aConn;
          aReader = aCmd.ExecuteReader();

          while (aReader.Read())
          {

             //I have a Fruit constructor that goes:  Fruit(string Name, string Color) in another class named Fruit.cs, and I use it here for this form.
             aFruit[0] = new Fruit(aReader["Name"].ToString(), aReader["Color"].ToString());
             aFruit[1] = new Fruit(aReader["Name"].ToString(), aReader["Color"].ToString());
             aFruit[2] = new Fruit(aReader["Name"].ToString(), aReader["Color"].ToString());
          }

     private void PresentationGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}

     //Intended Output:  when the user clicks on picBox1 (showing an image of an apple) it should display 'Apple' for label1 and 'red' for label2
    //Reality:  it displays 'Apple' for label1 and 'Red' for label2
     private void picBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
               this.label1.Text = aFruit[0].Name.ToString();
               this.label2.Text = aFruit[0].Color.ToString();
         }
         catch (NullReferenceException) {....}
     }

     //Intended Output:  when the user clicks on picBox2 (showing an image of an Banana) it should display 'Banana' for label1 and 'yellow' for label2
    //Reality:  it displays 'Apple' for label1 and 'Red' for label2
     private void picBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
               this.label1.Text = aFruit[1].Name.ToString();
               this.label2.Text = aFruit[1].Color.ToString();
         }
         catch (NullReferenceException) {....}
     }

     //Intended Output:  when the user clicks on picBox2 (showing an image of an Pear) it should display 'Pear' for label1 and 'green' for label2
    //Reality:  it displays 'Apple' for label1 and 'Red' for label2
    private void picBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
               this.label1.Text = aFruit[2].Name.ToString();
               this.label2.Text = aFruit[2].Color.ToString();
         }
         catch (NullReferenceException) {....}
     }

     }
}
```

Why does it only display the first row of my database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading the same value into your array three times, so try changing your While statement like this:

```
int fruitCounter = 0
while (aReader.Read())
{
    //I have a Fruit constructor that goes:  Fruit(string Name, string Color) in another class named Fruit.cs, and I use it here for this form.
    aFruit[fruitCounter] = new Fruit(aReader["Name"].ToString(), aReader["Color"].ToString());
    fruitCounter++;

    if(fruitCounter > aFruit.Length)
    {
          break;
    }
}
```

I would suggest that you first get the number of rows to be returned by your query and then initialize your array based upon that value.

Comment: Nice!  That worked... kinda.  Except now my rows seemed to be reversed:  it's displaying Pear, green for the first one then Banana, yellow for second and last is Apple, red when it should be the other way around.  Should I set the counter to 3 and decrement it instead?

Comment: How about adding an Order by in your Select Statement ie sql = "SELECT * FROM Fruits_Table ORDER BY . . . ";